# 230VAC line voltage sensing using MCU pin

Tags: microcontroller, mains, opto-isolator, emc, surge-protection

I Am designing a circuit to detect the presence of AC line voltage.It is basically to detect the switch On/OFF for a load.
Here is the circuit.
[image]

Here Input resistor ladder to step down the voltage. Varistor added to get it away from surge (Fuse included). zener to protect the opto. Opto is darlington with transistor to reduce the opto input current and therefor the input resistor losses.

Since this going to commercial product i would like to gather some info on reliability and surge protection.

1) Is this circuit good enough to handle potential surges/Back emf from inductive loads.
2) Is there any better/cost effective alternatives.
4) I am using 8 in my board to detect 8 channels all are powered from same AC source. Is there a way to consolidate these and reduce overall cost?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my opinion it's too much complicated. I would eliminate varistors, caps, zener , R29 and R26. Instead of zener I would add a diode. Or maybe better if you use an optocoupler with two internal LEDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simplified version of your schematics, that should work equal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNJCU1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For example SFH628A-4 has a CTR ratio of 250 at 0.5mA IF current. The absolute maximum allowed forward current is 50mA. The insulation resistance is 5.3kV. So at 5.3kV spike, the current trough diode would be 5300/440= 12mA, which is far from absoulte rating.

Comment: It will work. How about the high voltage/Surge?

Comment: And resistor is rated to 200V. So is it not a good idea to connect resistors in series to get more bandwidth like energy meter?

Comment: Of course, you can make a string of resistors if you want. The surge won't burn your led easily, you can calculate Vsurge/Rin to get the current. 5kV/440kohm= 11.mA that current is easily handled by LED. If the current of 0.5mA through LED is enough to detect on your MCU, that's another story.

Comment: Yes I am using this circuit and its working fine. Since the Darlington coupled transistor gives out put atleast 2/3 of total waveform

Comment: The panasonic ERJUP8  SMD resistor 1206 accepts max 1kV spike.

Comment: Here D11 act as antiparallel diode also. So during positive half cycle it will clam the voltage @5V.

Comment: So basically R26 not doing anything great? R29, C11 form a low pass filter which will suppress if any spike or short term false trigger. Don't they?

Comment: R29 is current limiting for the LED, since the voltage is 5V from zener. C11 is used to supply current in the next half period when zener acts like diode. R26 is almost useless, again some voltage limiting for the zener. Your circuit is a protection for zener and cap, eliminating them you do filtering on the low voltage side with a capacitor, much easier.

Comment: @Marko, is this design doing well with 12-24VAC input values? And what about 12-24VDC, will the two leds get enough low power to turn on the output?

Comment: @LordAnubis Of course, but you have to re-calculate the resistors R1 and R2. For such low voltage, one resistor is enough. 24VAC equals to cca 34V peak to peak, so a single resistor of 22kohm would give you approx. 1mA forward current on 24VDC.